# Adding values after a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have created a query that gets two values. It outputs the correct values but now i want to add these values together to get one value in a column named "Total Cost". Is this possible if "Total Cost" is not a column in my tables?

Here is the query i used:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(drugcost_cost),0) FROM drugcost UNION SELECT ROUND(SUM(operation_cost),0) FROM operation
```

[image: output with code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this with subqueries:

```
SELECT d.dcost, o.ocost, (d.dcost + o.ocost) as totalcost
FROM (SELECT ROUND(SUM(drugcost_cost),0) as dcost FROM drugcost) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ROUND(SUM(operation_cost),0) as ocost FROM operation) o;
```

By the way, your query is an excellent example of why you should always use `union all` *unless* you really know why you want `union` instead.  If the values from the two subqueries are the same, then `union` will remove duplicates -- and you will get only one row.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'o.cost' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3411002 . . . Typo fixed.

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted! Thanks, i see now why to use UNION ALL instead, it makes more sense but a cross join is more fitting for this